# model related to User model by foreign key problem

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django and have a totally newbie question.
When someone logs in the system it should be able to register it's football team for instance...

here's my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Equipo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # new
    Fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    RUT = models.TextField()
```

here's my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import CrearFT

def dashboard (request):
    crear_ft = CrearFT()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        crear_ft = CrearFT(data=request.POST)
        if crear_ft.is_valid():
            crear_ft.save()
            return redirect(reverse('dashboard')+'?ok')
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('dashboard')+'?error') 
           
    return render(request, 'vets/dashboard.html', {'form':crear_ft})
```

here's my form:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Equipo

class CrearFT(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Equipo
        fields = "__all__"
```

The thing is that when I make the form in the view and run it, I can select the more than 1 user, I can see all users.
Is there a way so the user is implicit?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Tv6.png)

Also a logged in user might have more than one football team, so I should be able to register more than one...

I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

1. Edit your form and exclude `user`

```py
class CrearFT(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Equipo
        exclude = ['user']
```

2. In your view before saving form, assign logged-in user to the form. Make sure that the dashboard view is protected and can only be accessed by authenticated users. You can use the `@login_required` decorator like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       crear_ft = CrearFT(data=request.POST)
       if crear_ft.is_valid():
           equipo = crear_ft.save(commit=False)
           equipo.user = request.user
           equipo.save()
           return redirect(reverse('dashboard') + '?ok')
       else:
           return redirect(reverse('dashboard') + '?error')
   else:
       crear_ft = CrearFT()
   return render(request, 'vets/dashboard.html', {'form': crear_ft})
```

With these changes, the user field will be automatically set to the logged-in user when the form is saved, and the field will not be visible or editable in the form itself.